# tabbing numbering and alignat numbering

Tags: numbering, align, tabbing

Is there a way for the tabbing environment `\begin{tabbing}` to number equations and sync up with the `align` or `alignat` environments?

If I use `align` or `alignat`, each successive use is numbered appropriate even when `\notag` is used.

Can the `tabbing` environment recognize `aligns` numbering system and then use it?

If so, how?

Comment: Can you please provide an illustration of what you're after? Even if it means drawing it on paper and including a scanned image. Perhaps it's just me, but I'm not entirely sure what you're after...

Comment: Apologies. Upvoted the question by accident (meant to upvote @werner's comment) but cannot undo upvoting the question.

Comment: If you want no numbering, use the `*` variants: like `align*`, `alignat*` and so on...

Comment: @kan I understand the no numbering situation but sometimes you have an equation evolving through simplification so you use `\notag` so only the final result is numbered.

Comment: @Werner how am I supposed to illustrate a concept?  Have you used the tabbing environment before?  The advantage of it for me is that if you have a set of equations that is going to go to the next page, the whole system won't move down as with `align`.  Tabbing only drops the equations down that won't fit on the page.  Therefore, I use `tabbing` instead of `align`.  But `tabbing` doesn't number equations like `align`.  How can `tabbing` number equations and follow along with the current numbering system.

Comment: @kan no.  If `align` just numbered an equation `(5)` and I am going to use tabbing but I want the equation to be numbered as well, I would like it to be `(6)`.

Comment: OK! I understand the question hopefully now! I think I also can provide an answer... I'll write one now.

Comment: Look at examples in [mathmode by Herbert](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically asking how you'd number a line in a tabbing environment. It is straightforward to define a counter and trigger it when needed.

Here is an implementation:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newcommand{\tagthisaux}{%
\refstepcounter{equation}%
(\theequation)%
}
\newcommand{\tagthisline}{\`\tagthisaux} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
1+ 1 &= 2 & 2 &= 3- 1 
\end{align}
\begin{tabbing}
 $1+1 = 0$ \= $\Rightarrow$ \= $1 = -1$ \= since $F$ is of characteristic $2$ \tagthisline \\
 second row \>  \> more 
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image: eqn.png]

Some caveats:

- You'll consistently have to number on the right.
- This code works on a (reasonable) assumption that, you're going to demand that the line be numbered, at the end of the line: that is, the `\tagthisline` is the last tabstop.

Comment: does `\tagthisline` continue numbering from where `align` left off?

Comment: Yes, it does. But, note that, you'd have to consistently number on the right. I'll update my answer to reflect and also think of possible workarounds.