# Enjoy `tabbing` logic in equation mode

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, alignat, tabbing

I always find myself writing this:

```
\begin{align}
    once\ &upon \\
     &a\ long\ &time \nonumber \\ % introduce a new mark
     &i\ was\ &time-aligned
\end{align}
```

and getting this:

[image]

Because I actually intended to use this good'ol `tabbing` logic, where you could add new marks on any line:

```
\begin{tabbing}
once \=upon \\
\> a long \=time \\ % introduce a new mark
\> i was \> time-aligned
\end{tabbing}
```

[image]

How to enjoy the best of both worlds?
How do I add new alignements marks in subsequent lines in equation mode?

Comment: See `alignat`... as in `\begin{alignat}{2}
    once\ &upon \\
     &a\ &time \nonumber \\ % introduce a new mark
     & . &time-aligned
\end{alignat}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes [`alignat`](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) makes you explicitly define the number of columns, and makes it impossible that columns overlap, right? (like if it was `upooooooon` in my examples, nothing should be changed in subsequent lines)

Comment: The way to get "time" to overlap within the "upon" group is to nest the align groups

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Well, it seems that `\begin{align}\begin{align}nested\end{align}\end{align}` does not compile. What do you mean exactly with "nest the align groups"? õ.Ô

Comment: `\begin{alignat}{2}
    once\ &upon \\&
     \begin{alignedat}{3}
       &a\ &&
     time \nonumber \\ % introduce a new mark
      &.&& time-aligned
    \end{alignedat}
\end{alignat}`

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110784/15925 help?

Comment: You can use an array.  Like tabular, you specify each column (r,l,c and @{}).

Comment: @AndrewSwann It does, thanks :) This is not equation mode anymore so it raises a few more problems: `\=` and `\>` are not allowed in math mode so I'll have to leave/re-enter equation mode manually on each mark (can we alias `$\=$\displaystyle` and `$\>$\displaystyle` to something shorter?). And the equations are not centered anymore since this is `tabbing` logic (is there a centered-tabbing logic?).

Comment: @JohnKormylo In this case, I'll loose the natural spacing, right? I'll have to 1) nest several tables so that the column `upon` contains several subcolumns and 2) manually tweak  `\tabcolsep` until the spacing between `a` and `time` looks natural.. artificially ;)

Comment: Glad to hear the other question is useful. The material you show in your example is text not math.  Do you have another use in mind? If not may be we should close as a duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewSwann My actual material is math. I have chosen plain words in my example instead for the sake of clarity, but you may mentally replace them by any kind of fiddly `$\forall t \in \mathbb{R},\quad \exists\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\ / \ a + b - z \neq t \dots$` *etc.* ;)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This does help, thanks :) However, the lines in `alignedat` inner environment seem considered a single object and are only given one tag number. How to number all lines independently in the inner `alignedat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to retain the numbering ability for each individual line, you will have to stick with `alignat` rather than adding `alignedat` nesting, as I had earlier suggested in a comment.  However, when a line no longer needs to follow subsequent alignments, you can just put it in a `\mathrlap`, if that helps your situation.

Here, there is alignment of `upon`, `quite`, and `i`, as well as alignment of `time` and `time`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}    once\ &\mathrlap{upon\ (and\ I\ mean\ really\ upon)}&&\\
     &quite\ a\ long\ &&time \nonumber \\ % introduce a new mark
     &i\ was\ &&time-aligned
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For right-alignment, as shown in one of the OP's examples, just play with the number of `&` tabs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}    once\ &\mathrlap{upon\ (and\ I\ mean\ really\ upon)}&\\
     &quite\ a\ long\ &time \nonumber \\ % introduce a new mark
     &i\ was\ &time-aligned
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this nails it. It is *almost* tabbing-logic-like, and it does fullfill all my requirements. Thanks a lot :) (I didn't know about `\math*lap`..)